# How to use PointZ type in Spring boot with PostGIS database

Tags: spring-boot, postgis

I want to use PointZ type to store `latitude`, `longitude` and `altitude`. How should I do? My kotlin code as below:

```
import org.springframework.data.geo.Point
import javax.persistence.Column
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.Table

@Table(name = "walks")
class WalkEntity(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        val wid: Long,

        @Column(columnDefinition = "geometry(PointZ)")
        val center: Point,
        @Column(columnDefinition = "geometry(PointZ)")
        val start: Point,
        @Column(columnDefinition = "geometry(PointZ)")
        val end: Point,
        @Column(columnDefinition = "geometry(PointZ)")
        val top: Point
) {
}
```

The class `Point` only has `x` and `y` attributes, no `z`. So how to represent PostGIS's pointZ type in java or kotlin code.

Answer (score 0):

`Point` type object from `jts-core` library can be used for 3D point. We can get Z coordinate in coordinate list of `Point` object.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, I used this library in my project. I can insert point to database but I can't update z value of the point when I want to only z value. Do you know any solution for this problem?